# Abstract class override error

Tags: java

Hello after having puzzeled a bit I have created the following code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Tri extends RandomShape{

 public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
 // create random variables for collor and shape of triangle
int x;
int y;
int x2;
int y2;

x = (int) Math.random()*100;
y = (int) Math.random()*100;
x2 = (int) Math.random()*100; 
y2 = (int) Math.random()*100;

int r1;
int g1;
int b1;
r1 = (int) Math.random()*255;
g1 = (int) Math.random()*255;
b1 = (int) Math.random()*255;
 Color color = new Color(r1,g1,b1);
 //draw triangle

 g.setColor(color);
 g.drawLine(x,y,y2,y);
 g.setColor(color);
 g.drawLine(x,y,y2,y2);
 g.setColor(color);
 g.drawLine(y2,y,y2,y2);


}
}
```

and my randomshape code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

/**
*
* @author huub
*/
abstract class RandomShape {    
/** color used for drawing this shape **/
protected Color color;  
/** position of the shape (upper left corner) **/
protected int x, y;  

abstract void draw(Graphics g);
}
```

however when i try and compile it gives an error that Tri is not abstract and does not override abstract method draw in Randomshape how could i fix this

Comment: Do you know what `abstract` means in the context of methods and classes?

Comment: _how could i fix this_ The error is clear. Override the `draw` method in the `Tri` class.

Comment: The error message is telling you **exactly** what's wrong. Time to crack open your textbook and read up on abstract classes!

Answer (score 3):

In abstract class you have an abstract method called draw. The class that extends abstract class should override this method. So in your case you should have an implementation for draw(Graphics g) method inside Tri class.
Otherwise you have to declare Tri class as abstract.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

you are extending a class which has abstract method so to resolve this error you should either (correctly)override the draw method in child class or declare the child class as abstract.

go through this page.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

http://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap52/ch52_4.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Tri extends RandomShape{

   void draw(Graphics g){ //You must implement this method
   }

}
```

or

You need to make Tri class to abstract

```
  public abstract class Tri extends RandomShape{

  }
```